# Angular Datatables with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, dependency-injection, datatables

I have an HTML table that is dynamically loaded from an ng-repeat directive and am using Datatable-AngularJS to modify it. The table looks something like this:

```
<table datatable="ng" class="row-border hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Song Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="song in Songs">
        <td>{{song.song_name}}</td>
        <td>{{song.song_type}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting an error in my console with TypeError: undefined is not a function. I THINK it's because of the way Angular-Datatables works. They ask you to include the bootstrapped files in this way:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="mybootstrap.js"></script>
```

But the thing is, when the datatables loads, the table has not been populated yet (because of the fact my bootstrapped js file is below that populates it. So I changed it to this:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="mybootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
```

But I still get the same error, when I put it like this:

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="mybootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
```

I get a loading... that does nothing below and the raw html table is loaded. I have a feeling it has something to do with the async nature of AngularJS and that datatables is being loaded before the table is being populated by my bootstrapped js file. How can I fix this? Any ideas?

Comment: This is the specific error: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.e [as showLoading]

Answer (score 4):

It seems your want to use the Angular renderer. So you need to add the `ng` value in your datatable directive:

```
<table datatable="ng" class="row-border hover">
```

Comment: Oops, I included an outdated. I already included ng before, but all it did was  give me a big Loading....

Answer (score 0):

Try arranging to this:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="mybootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the one as suggested by I-lin and it works

```
<table datatable="ng" class="row-border hover">
```